# New Column Based on Last Delimiter Split

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting an index error while trying to use a lambdas function like below... I am trying to extract just the last 2-3 characters from the string based on a space as a delimiter. Why would this not work?

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\robert.carmody\OneDrive - Accenture\Python\Global T&O Learning.py", line 116, in <module>
    report_demand['Industry'] = report_demand['Industry'].apply(lambda x: x.rsplit(' ', 1)[1])
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 3848, in apply
    mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
  File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 2329, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "C:\Users\robert.carmody\Global T&O Learning.py", line 116, in <lambda>
    report_demand['Industry'] = report_demand['Industry'].apply(lambda x: x.rsplit(' ', 1)[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Code:

```
report_demand['Industry'] = report_demand['Industry'].astype(str)
report_demand['Industry'] = report_demand['Industry'].apply(lambda x: x.rsplit(' ', 1)[1])
```

example string: "Newport Chicago IL" or "Kingston Jamaica USR"

expected output: "IL" and "USR"

Comment: Your code works fine for me. However, it will give an index error if you have values in that column that don't contain spaces. Therefore, you should change your index number from  `[1]` to `[-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the last element of the list, then you would need to use `[-1]` instead of `[1]`. Furthermore, there's no need for apply + lambda, you can use `.str.split()`. Try with the following:

```
report_demand['Industry'] = report_demand['Industry'].str.split().str[-1]
```